# Why maxwells speed distribution law doesn’t violet special theory if relativity

Tags: special-relativity, maxwell-equations, ideal-gas, gas

As per maxwells distribution law the molecule of gas will have speed across zero to infinity with some probability function. I want to know that why the speed above speed of light is possible (i know that its probability will be very less i mean really less, but it would be non zero.). Doesn’t it violet Special theory of relativity?

Comment: Hi Avinash. See the question I've linked. The Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution is an approximation that applies only for non-relativistic speeds. The relativistic version is the [Maxwell-Jüttner distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%E2%80%93J%C3%BCttner_distribution).

Comment: Thanks sir. I got it.